# Installing cabinet hinges backwards?

Tags: woodworking, cabinets, carpentry, hinges, hardware

I have a frameless cabinet hinge like [this](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Everbilt-35-mm-110-Degree-Full-Overlay-Soft-Close-Cabinet-Hinge-1-Pair-H32636E-NP-CP/302857903) that I bought for a closet-like piece I am building. However, I quickly realized there was a problem; the hinge is designed so that the door lays flat in front of the frame, while in my design the door sits flush within the frame. I was on the verge of giving up and trying to find new hinges when I thought that maybe I could just flip around the hinges, install the cabinet frame piece on the door and the door piece on the cabinet frame, this way that the hinge will effectively place the door flush with the frame. I know that this is not typically done, but can anyone see a possible problem with this?

Basically I want to flip around an overlay hinge to get an inset hinge.

Comment: I think that I follow you but there is no way to be sure. Please provide a diagram or picture to better communicate what it is that you're trying to do. A picture is worth a 1000 words...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you're going to be able to do that with this hinge. There are a few tactical issues. First, the hinge requires a mortise which would typically be on the inside of the door. So now you'll have to figure out how to cut the mortise on the inside of the cabinet frame. Second, The hinge is a 110 degree hinge but it's meant to swing in the opposite direction so it will want to swing in instead of out.
I won't get into the fulcrum point of the hinge which will be a non-issue since I don't think the hinge will functionally do what you want it to do.
**Buy new hinges!**